# . Create an “Employee Roster” report listing the Manager’s name and the name of the employees who report to that manager

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I think that I should use a join here, however, I am not quite sure how the report comes up in SQL because the employees and manager they report to are in the same table[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOYFN.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please post your sql code.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle this would be handled most elegantly by the recursive functions available through the "CONNECT BY PRIOR" function.  As you have indicated you're operating outside of Oracle, you must alias your table twice.   In addition, you haven't indicated if it's possible for a manager to have no employees or an employee to have no manager -- in either of these cases you will need to consider an "OUTER JOIN" condition.  Following is the code for the simple case:  Every employee has a manager and every manager has employees:

```
Select m.lastname manager_last,
m.firstname  manager_first,
e.lastname employee_last, e.firstname employee_first
from employee_list e, employee_list m
where e.reports_to = m.employee_number
order by m.lastname, m.firstname, e.lastname, e.firstname
```